# Getting the top 10 stores within a category

Tags: optimization, performance, sql, mysql

I have the following query. I know there's an easier way to do this without the sub queries, or at least optimizing how they're used. I've read about cross joins and using `HAVING` but cannot figure out how to make this better as I know it's pretty bad.

Basically what I'm trying to do is get the top 10 stores within a category. For this category it is category with an `id` of 9 as you can see in the where clause. I am categorizing each individual user based on the most occurring category of the products they have. And then reordering the results by most orders and getting the first 10 results.

EDIT:

c.id = 9, which should be c.id = '$categoryId' (edited) is representative of where a numeric value would be passed into the query to get the top stores specific to a category id.

```
SELECT u.id, 
       u.avatar, 
       u.storeName,
       (SELECT COUNT(o.id) FROM orders o WHERE o.storeId = u.id) AS orders
FROM users u
WHERE (SELECT c.id
       FROM categories c, products p
       WHERE c.id = p.categoryId
       AND p.userId = u.id
       GROUP BY p.categoryId
       ORDER BY COUNT(p.id) DESC
       LIMIT 1) = '$categoryId'
ORDER BY orders DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Why not just use `WHERE c.id = 9`? Do you need to make sure it exists in the products table?

Comment: It only exists in the products table, and we want to get the most frequently occuring ID

Comment: [Please join me in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15804/sql) I have some questions.

Answer (score 3):

There are some things that you don't need here

```
SELECT u.id, 
       u.avatar, 
       u.storeName,
       (SELECT COUNT(o.id) FROM orders o WHERE o.storeId = u.id) AS orders
FROM users u
WHERE (SELECT c.id
       FROM categories c, products p
       WHERE c.id = p.categoryId
       AND p.userId = u.id
       GROUP BY p.categoryId
       ORDER BY COUNT(p.id) DESC
       LIMIT 1) = 9
ORDER BY orders DESC
LIMIT 10
```

like the `ORDER BY` and the `LIMIT 1` and the `GROUP BY` in the Select statement that is nested in your where clause.

```
SELECT u.id, 
       u.avatar, 
       u.storeName,
       (SELECT COUNT(o.id) FROM orders o WHERE o.storeId = u.id) AS orders
FROM users u
WHERE (SELECT c.id
       FROM categories c, products p
       WHERE c.id = p.categoryId
       AND p.userId = u.id
       ) = 9
ORDER BY orders DESC
LIMIT 10
```

You should also rename your column `orders` to `orderCount`

one more thing that I would suggest is to take it all out of the `WHERE` clause, this is slow

do it like this

```
SELECT u.id, 
       u.avatar, 
       u.storeName,
       (SELECT COUNT(o.id) FROM orders o WHERE o.storeId = u.id) AS orderCount
FROM users u INNER JOIN products p ON u.id = p.userId 
WHERE p.categoryID = 9
ORDER BY orderCount DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: It's not explicitly stated here, but it came out [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15804/sql) that there should be no results if the category is not the top category for a user.

Comment: oops @ckuhn203 I left that out of my query.

Answer (score 3):

You likely don't want to use `CROSS JOIN` as the performance is terrible and the cartesian product it returns is rarely useful. Instead, use `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN` etc.

---

I'm not a big fan of the way you named your table variables, but in such a tiny query I guess it's OK. `u`, `o`, `c`, `p` that would get really confusing in a larger script. `usr`, `ord`, `cat`, `prd` would at least give Mr. Maintainer an idea of what the variable means.

---

This:

```
   FROM categories cat, products prd
   WHERE cat.id = prd.categoryId
   AND prd.userId = usr.id
```

That is an old-style `JOIN` and [should not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11251836/3626537). Instead use this:

```
   FROM categories cat INNER JOIN products prd
   ON cat.id = prd.categoryId
   AND prd.userId = usr.id
```

---

So all this taken into account, here is how I would write your query:

```
SELECT usr.id, 
       usr.avatar, 
       usr.storeName,
       COUNT(ord.id) AS orders
FROM users usr
INNER JOIN orders ord ON ord.storeId = usr.id
WHERE (SELECT cat.id
       FROM categories cat, products prd
       WHERE cat.id = prd.categoryId
       AND prd.userId = usr.id
       GROUP BY prd.categoryId
       ORDER BY COUNT(prd.id) DESC
       LIMIT 1) = 9
ORDER BY COUNT(ord.id) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 3):

I add this as a separate answer because it doesn't follow the same path as my first answer.

---

You really don't need to grab the `category` table inside the sub query in the `WHERE` clause

it could look like this

```
SELECT u.id, 
       u.avatar, 
       u.storeName,
       (SELECT COUNT(o.id) FROM orders o WHERE o.storeId = u.id) AS orders
FROM users u
WHERE (SELECT p.categoryId
       FROM products p
       WHERE p.userId = u.id
       GROUP BY p.categoryId
       ORDER BY COUNT(p.id) DESC
       LIMIT 1) = 9
ORDER BY orders DESC
LIMIT 10
```

this would get rid of an extra table look-up that isn't needed inside of the `WHERE`,  if you can try to avoid using a sub query nested inside of a `WHERE` clause because that query will be run on every row returned by the containing query, it's like using a UDF in the `WHERE` clause in SQL Server,  it's horrible for performance.

I am sure you have a valid reason here, but I would definitely look into my other answer and see if it is going to give you the results you are looking for (which it should if I understand what you are doing correctly)

Comment: Ahh, right. That simplifies things a little. As for your previous answer, @ckuhn203 added in the comments, which I will edit my post to include, about the top category results being a factor.